# flowLayout.itemSize and flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I set the cell size in

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath).
```

However, in other callbacks of the collectionView I see that the flowLayout.itemSize is not the size I set, despite the size being correctly rendered on screen. Why is this not the case?

Separate but related-how/where do I set the flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing?

Answer (score 0):

So my answer might be kind of hack-ish but it works perfectly for me.

In

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

before I return I set the flowLayout.itemSize and minimumInteritemSpacing (in my case 1/6 the item size). Now whenever I call these I get the desired values.